# Lower radiator hose heater. Is it worth it?

Tags: toyota, radiator, heater

As winter and cold temperature are coming soon, I was looking at getting a block heater and I came across a thread talking about installing a lower radiator hose heater. Does anyone have one installed? Is it working as good as a block heater? I'm thinking about installing one on my Toyota Land Cruiser 87 (Diesel)

Here an [installation on a Jeep](http://www.jeepforum.com/forum/f12/coolant-flush-lower-radiator-hose-heater-writeup-326995/), if you want to know what it looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How cold is it where you are? A lower radiator hose wouldn't do much for you as it doesn't hold very much water and water tends to not change temperature easily.

Comment: I live in Canada, so temperature are mostly below the freezing point for about 5 months per year. In the coldest winter day I can easily reach -30C. I hope my radiator does not contains water, if so it will easily freeze inside hoses!

Comment: OK. Then I would look into some kind of oil pan/block heater.